# Can i install Apache Hue for Hadoop in Windows?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hue, webhdfs, bigdata

I am working on Hadoop but searching for a better open source HDFS explorer. Ended up with [Apache Hue](http://gethue.com/).

For Linux there are manuals but what about for Windows?

Comment: What is wrong with a terminal and `hdfs dfs -ls`?

Comment: Other than that, ["Hue is just a ‘view on top of any Hadoop distribution’ and can be installed on any machine."](http://gethue.com/how-to-configure-hue-in-your-hadoop-cluster/)

Comment: @cricket_007 can you please give detailed idea. I am new to big data

Comment: Hue is just a web server that you point at a hadoop installation. The details of the installation are too broad to cover on StackOverflow.

Comment: Hue only works on Linux currently, you would need a Virtual Machine or boot under / connect to another OS